# changing background-color of a <tr> in react with useRef

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I created a plain dynamic table in react (not using react-table).  I want to change the background color of a clicked row.  I added ref to table:

but I'm not getting access to children ().

How can I change the style of a clicked row by id in a table in react?

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./TableBox.css";

const TableBox = ({ table_data }) => {
  const myTable = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("myTable", myTable.current);
  });

  const handlerRowClicked = (event) => {
    // console.log('clicked')
    // myTable.current.backgroundColor='blue'
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <table ref={myTable}>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            {Object.keys(table_data[0]).map((title) => (
              <th key={title}>{title}</th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {table_data.map((row, index) => (
            <tr key={index} id={index} onClick={handlerRowClicked}>
              {Object.keys(row).map((key) => (
                <td key={row[key]}>{row[key]}</td>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TableBox;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution that you can do is to save index of clicked row in state and use that as condition when looping trough `table_data`.

```js
const TableBox = ({ table_data }) => {
  const myTable = useRef(null);

  const [rowIndexClicked, setRowIndexClicked] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("myTable", myTable.current);
  });

  const handlerRowClicked = (rowIndex) => (event) => {
    if (rowIndexClicked !== rowIndex) {
      // handle if user clicks again the same row
      setRowIndexClicked(rowIndex);
    } else {
      setRowIndexClicked(null); // set clicked row to null if same row is selected
    }
  };

  return (
    ...
          {table_data.map((row, index) => (
            <tr
              key={index}
              id={index}
              className={rowIndexClicked === index ? "clicked-class" : ""}
              onClick={handlerRowClicked(index)}
            >
              {Object.keys(row).map((key) => (
                <td key={row[key]}>{row[key]}</td>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
    ...
  );
};
```

Using `useRef` wont give you any edge. You can store clicked element in it, but there is not reason not to go the simplest way.

**SOLUTION 2**

If you still want to take id from the clicked element itself you can just use `event` that you inherently get from click event:

```js
const TableBox = ({ table_data }) => {
  const myTable = useRef(null);

  const [rowIndexClicked, setRowIndexClicked] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("myTable", myTable.current);
  });

  const handlerRowClicked = (event) => {
    const { id } = event.currentTarget;
    if (rowIndexClicked !== id) {
      // handle if user clicks again the same row
      setRowIndexClicked(id);
    } else {
      setRowIndexClicked(null); // set clicked row to null if same row is selected
    }
  };

  return (
    ...
          {table_data.map((row, index) => (
            <tr
              key={index}
              id={index}
              className={rowIndexClicked === index ? "clicked-class" : ""}
              onClick={handlerRowClicked}
            >
              {Object.keys(row).map((key) => (
                <td key={row[key]}>{row[key]}</td>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
    ...
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Using refs for this purpose is most likely an over kill.
Instead, I'd suggest you to `useState`, and attach either a `className` or `style`.

For instance:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import './TableBox.css'

const TableBox = ({ table_data }) => {
    const [selectedRow, setSelectedRow] = useState(-1);
    ...

    const handlerRowClicked = useCallback((event) => {
         // if you insist to use `id`
         const { id } = event.currentTarget;
         setSelectedRow(id);
     }, [])
...
<table>
 ...
   <tr onClick={handlerRowClicked} className={selectedRow === index ? 'selected: ''}>
```

There are some better practices how to handle `className` but this shows the idea.